# Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I have a C# Web API application that uses Entity Framework 6.0

Inside a section of my application I have javascript code that runs a `setInterval` every 5000 seconds to check the status of some data.

It appears to works perfect but sometimes I notice in my chrome console I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

So this time I attach the web process and after some minutes I get an error in Visual Studio:

> Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is closed.

The code that generates the error:

```
//validate session here, EndSessionDate must be null in order to be 
//an Active Session
var activeSession = Uow.SecuritySessions.GetAll()
    .Where(s => s.SessionUid == new Guid(sessionId) && 
        s.UserId.ToString() == userId && s.EndSessionDate == null)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It happens sometimes, sometimes not, don't know if it could be my internet connection but its annoying.

Does anyone know what could be generating the issue or how to workaround to solve this?

**UPDATED**

Here is my UnitofWork implementation:

http://pastebin.com/bWHzYDXs

Comment: We don't have the code to UoW, so we can't guess what it's doing. You should add that and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Uow is Unit of Work Pattern

Comment: I know what the UoW pattern is. But I don't know your implementation. We don't have enough information to help you. I can *guess* that the lifetime management of your DbContext is incorrect, but I cannot know for sure without the code and the stacktrace.

Comment: Let me upload the code Diego. Appreciate your help

Comment: I just added a link to the code of my Unit of Work implementation Diego. Thanks

Comment: Still missing the stacktrace. Your code does not change ConnectionString; we need to see who does.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon how can I get the stacktrace? I guess I have to wait until the error happens and then in visual studio go to debug-windows-callstack right?

Comment: Yes... Actually, when the exception happens, I usually quickwatch `$exception.ToString()`. But I see a bunch of logging code there. Are you not logging the exceptions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58028/discussion-between-vaaa-and-diego-mijelshon).